# Type casting and sorting two arrays in java

Tags: java, sorting, casting, long-integer

I'm trying to sort an array in java using the inbuilt comparator and sort method but it is giving me an error `incompatible type, object cannot be converted to int`

I want to sort an array and also want to index changes apply to another array, e.g. sorting marks and id of students, instead if getting a sorted array, i got errors

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Solution
{
    public String largestNumber(int[] nums)
    {
        int n = nums.length;
        long[] max = new long[n];
        long[] id = new long[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            id[i] = (long) nums[i];
            max[i] = changeNum(nums[i]); //return type of changeNum is long cant code it because the website wont allow it
        }

        Arrays.sort(id, Comparator.comparingLong(i -> max[i]));

        return "";
    }


that my code and following is the error i got
Line 21: error: no suitable method found for sort(long[],Comparator<Object>)
        Arrays.sort(id, Comparator.comparingLong(i -> max[i]));
              ^
    method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: long
        lower bounds: Object)
    method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)
Line 21: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int
        Arrays.sort(id, Comparator.comparingLong(i -> max[i]));
                                                          ^
2 errors
```

Comment: i know that the camparator cannot sort primitives but when using it with int,Integer it works fine
in this case i used it as long,Long

Comment: `return IntStream.of(nums).max().orElseThrow();` Not sure why you'd want to return `String` though, but trivial to fix if that's necessary for some reason

Comment: If you look at [the methods of the Arrays class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#method-summary), you will see that there are two `sort` methods that accept `long[]`.  Those methods are `sort(long[])` (which takes one argument) and `sort(long[], int, int)` (which takes three arguments).  There is no sort method which takes a `long[]` and a Comparator, which is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: ohk, thanks
i use this method just for sorting cases like this, i haven't studied it so it was a creating confusion